# SQL Server error - Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014. The last line causes causes an overflow error.

Why?

```
  DECLARE @CurrentDateTime  datetime
  DECLARE @PreviousYearDateTime  datetime
  DECLARE @ModifiedStartDateTime  datetime
  DECLARE @YearsYear   int = 2015

  SET @CurrentDateTime = '2016-08-29 19:13:30.840'      
  SET @PreviousYearDateTime = CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @CurrentDateTime))

  -- For the "startdate" - just use the previous "startdate".
  SET @ModifiedStartDateTime = @PreviousYearDateTime

  -- Set the 'year' to the year value.
  SET @ModifiedStartDateTime = DATEADD(YEAR, @YearsYear, DATEADD(YEAR, -DATEPART(YEAR, @ModifiedStartDateTime), @ModifiedStartDateTime))
```

Comment: Some simple debugging should reveal the issue. You are trying to set the year to 0 which is not valid. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you are trying to achieve with the code? There may be an easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the year like so:

```
SET @ModifiedStartDateTime = REPLACE(@ModifiedStartDateTime,DATEPART(YEAR,@ModifiedStartDateTime),@YearsYear)
```

But since you set the `@ModifiedStartDateTime = @PreviousYearDateTime` which has the year 2015... and you are changing the year to 2015... you aren't doing anything. Try using something different than 2015 for you `@YearsYear`

Answer (score -1):

SQL **[Datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)**

> Date range January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

When you substract 2015 you are on year 0

There is [**DateTime2**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

> range: 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31. 
>   January 1,1 CE through December 31, 9999 CE

[how to solve 1753 year issue in sqlserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908548/how-to-solve-1753-year-issue-in-sqlserver)

[What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

Comment: When i execute "select dateadd(year, 0, 0)"  , it gives me "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000". why not "1753-01-01" ?

Comment: I guess was [**sql design**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)  `The argument for date is the number 0. SQL Server interprets 0 as January 1, 1900.`

Comment: Thank you!! Above two links (great great great grandfather) are very useful.